# Query (SQL Server) to get value from node in XML column stored as varchar(max)?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I hate dealing with XML queries. I don't do it often enough to remember how to format everything, but I'm at my wits' end.
Let's say I have a table called Messages and a column inside it called Payload. Payload contains XML stored as varchar(max). The XML is formatted as such:

```html
<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">
  
<VID>3656183</VID>
  
</NCOAPACP>
```

How do I query the table to retrieve a list of the values in the VID node?

Comment: So if it's `XML` - why isn't it *stored* in a `XML` column?!?!?

Comment: @marc_s i had to deal with this kind of xml stored in varchar(max) mostly sql server xml field are limited https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107(SQL.90).aspx and still doesnt support utf8 https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/362867/add-support-for-storing-utf-8-natively-in-sql-server

Comment: @Fredou: `XML` is limited to 2 GB - just like `nvarchar(max)`; `XML` does not support UTF-8, just like `nvarchar(max)`. **BUT**: `XML` stores your data in a **highly optimized, tokenized** fashion - *unlike*  `nvarchar(max)`, and `XML` allows you to use XQuery methods - unlike `nvarchar(max)` ..... so again: **why** aren't you using `XML` ??

Comment: @marc_s because... hmm since when sql server accept xml declaration with encoding="utf-8" ? it never worked for me before now (just tried it) it was always complaining that utf-16 was required and that utf-8 was not supported in xml field

Comment: @Fredou: UTF-8 is not supported **anywhere** in SQL Server - not in `nvarchar(max)` either ....

Comment: But this works just fine: `INSERT INTO tableName(columns) VALUES(...., '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><NCOAPACP />');` so how are you inserting your XML? What exactly do you get as an error? Maybe the problem is really more *how* to get this XML data into your SQL Server (rather than querying it...)

Comment: @marc_s been a while since i had that error, it seem i cannot get it under sql 2012 and i don't have access to a 2008 or 2005 to test it. going to stop there since this is not my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @w as xml = cast('
<NCOAPACP xmlns:i=''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance''
 xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">

 <VID>3656183</VID>

 </NCOAPACP>' as xml)


 SELECT @w.value('declare namespace ns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM";
                   ns:NCOAPACP[1]/ns:VID[1]','varchar(10)') AS VID
```

If you have multiple VID node you can try this:

```
declare @w as xml = cast('
    <NCOAPACP xmlns:i=''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance''
xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">

<VID>3656183</VID>
<VID>454545</VID>

</NCOAPACP>' as xml)


 SELECT VID.value('.','varchar(10)')
 from @w.nodes(
    'declare namespace ns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM";
    ns:NCOAPACP[1]/ns:VID'
    ) 
    AS C(VID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If XML data are in a table column then the solution is a little more tricky. Especially if data type is `varchar(max)`.

```
declare @tbl table(id int,payload varchar(max))--sample table
--sample data
insert @tbl values 
(1,'<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">
<VID>3656183</VID>
<VID>3656184</VID>
</NCOAPACP>'),
(2,'<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">
<VID>123456</VID>
<VID>987654</VID>
</NCOAPACP>')

 --it is convenient to define namespaces before the query
;with xmlnamespaces('uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM' as x)--we will use this x:
select id, t.vid.value('.[1]','varchar(20)') vid 
-- . means self. [1] ensure single value
from 
--convert varchar(max) to xml first
(select id,cast(payload as xml) payload from @tbl) tt
cross apply
--convert xml to a tabular form
tt.payload.nodes('//x:VID') t(vid)
```

Results:

```
id  vid
1   3656183
1   3656184
2   123456
2   987654
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this

```
DECLARE @Messages TABLE(ID INT, Payload NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Messages(ID, Payload) VALUES(1, '<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM"> <VID>3656183</VID> </NCOAPACP>')
INSERT INTO @Messages(ID, Payload) VALUES(2, '<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM"> <VID>3656183</VID> <VID>3656184</VID> </NCOAPACP>')

;WITH CTE(ID, Payload) AS
(
    SELECT ID, CAST(Payload AS XML) 
    FROM @Messages
)
SELECT
ID, 
x.items.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(10)')
FROM CTE
CROSS APPLY Payload.nodes('declare namespace xx="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM"; xx:NCOAPACP/xx:VID') as x(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way (CTE `test` created just to get output, your xml value converted to `varchar(max)` as in your table, then `SELECT *.value`):

```
;WITH test AS (
SELECT CAST(
'<NCOAPACP xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="uri://www.gen.da.hob/VC/Contract/QualityManagement/EMSM">

<VID>3656183</VID>

</NCOAPACP>' as varchar(max)) as Payload
)

SELECT CAST(Payload as xml).value('(/*/*)[1]', 'int')
FROM test
```

Output:

```
3656183
```